# How do I use cookies in express session - connect.sid will soon be rejected

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, cookies

So in my app.js file I have this: `app.use(session({secret: 'mySecret', resave: false, saveUninitialized: false}));`

This works fine but comes up with a warning:

> Cookie “connect.sid” will be soon rejected because it has the
>   “sameSite” attribute set to “none” or an invalid value, without the
>   “secure” attribute. To learn more about the “sameSite“ attribute, read
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

Then it will randomly stop working. If I change session to this: `app.use(session({secret: 'mySecret', resave: false, saveUninitialized: false, sameSite: true, cookie: {secure: true}}));`it becomes undefined.

I am trying to save 2 different id's: req.session.qrID and req.session.visitID;

It is used in a number of post requests. What can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've just googled this warning i saw in the console and got here LOL.
It's actually related to express session cookie cross site policy that is set, more info here under cookie.sameSite
http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html

I got rid of mine by setting it to strict but you can also set it to none if you want

```
app.use(
session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET!,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: { sameSite: 'strict' },
  }),
);
```

Comment: You are my hero. I didn't put sameSite: 'strict' inside {} when I tried to get it working, thanks so much!