# session id is retrieved but session is undefined in nuxt

Tags: express, nuxt.js, cross-domain, session-cookies, express-session

- I have an express backend running on port 8000 with a single /login endpoint
- I have a nuxt frontend running on port 3000
- When I login via the frontend, the session is created in redis
- If I refresh the page, the session is undefined, however it is able to retrieve the session id

As per the screenshot below, notice in the console how the session ID is present but session is undefined

I have included only the relevant files on stackoverflow here,

[express backend code](https://github.com/Coinhexa/nuxt-session-undefined-backend) ,

[nuxt frontend code](https://github.com/Coinhexa/nuxt-session-undefined-frontend)

[image]

**My app.js backend file**

```
require("dotenv-flow").config();
const cors = require("cors");
const http = require("http");
const express = require("express");
const passport = require("passport");
const connectRedis = require("connect-redis");
const Redis = require("ioredis");
const expressSession = require("express-session");
const { Strategy: LocalStrategy } = require("passport-local");
const { Server } = require("ws");

const RedisStore = connectRedis(expressSession);

const client = new Redis({
  host: process.env.REDIS_SESSION_HOST,
  port: process.env.REDIS_SESSION_PORT,
  password: process.env.REDIS_SESSION_PASSWORD,
  db: process.env.REDIS_SESSION_DB,
});

const loggedInUser = {
  userId: 1,
  userName: process.env.TEST_USER_EMAIL,
  isAdmin: false,
};

const sessionParser = expressSession({
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  resave: process.env.SESSION_RESAVE === "true",
  rolling: process.env.SESSION_ROLLING === "true",
  saveUninitialized: process.env.SESSION_SAVE_UNINITIALIZED === "true",
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: process.env.SESSION_HTTP_ONLY === "true",
    // Doesnt work if maxAge is not of type Number
    maxAge: +process.env.SESSION_MAX_AGE,
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61999068/how-do-i-use-cookies-in-express-session-connect-sid-will-soon-be-rejected
    // https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-twitter/issues/101
    sameSite: process.env.SESSION_SAME_SITE === "true",
    secure: process.env.SESSION_SECURE === "true",
  },
  store: new RedisStore({ client }),
});

const app = new express();

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true,
  })
);

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.userId);
});
passport.deserializeUser(async (userId, done) => {
  done(null, loggedInUser);
});

passport.use(
  "local",
  new LocalStrategy(
    {
      usernameField: "email",
      passwordField: "password",
      badRequestMessage: "email or password is missing",
    },
    async (email, password, done) => {
      if (
        email === process.env.TEST_USER_EMAIL &&
        password === process.env.TEST_USER_PASSWORD
      ) {
        return done(null, loggedInUser);
      } else {
        return done(null, false);
      }
    }
  )
);

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(sessionParser);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.get("/user", (req, res) => {
  return res.json(req.user);
});
app.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate("local", {}, async (error, user, info) => {
    if (error) {
      return next(error);
    }
    if (!user) {
      return res.json(false);
    }
    req.logIn(user, (error) => {
      if (error) {
        return next(error);
      }
      return res.json(user);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});

app.post("/logout", (req, res, next) => {
  req.logout();
  req.session.destroy((err) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    req.user = null;
    res.clearCookie("connect.sid");
    return res.json(true);
  });
});

const map = new Map();

const server = http.createServer(app);

const websocketServer = new Server({ noServer: true });

server.on("upgrade", (request, socket, head) => {
  sessionParser(request, {}, () => {
    console.log(
      request.session,
      request.user,
      request.session.user,
      request.headers.cookie
    );

    websocketServer.handleUpgrade(request, socket, head, function (ws) {
      websocketServer.emit("connection", ws, request);
    });
  });
});

websocketServer.on("connection", function (ws, request) {
  const user = request.session.user;

  map.set(user, ws);

  ws.on("message", function (message) {
    //
    // Here we can now use session parameters.
    //
    console.log(`Received message ${message} from user ${user}`);
  });

  ws.on("close", function () {
    map.delete(user);
  });
});

server.listen(+process.env.PORT, () => console.log(`server listening on ${process.env.PORT}`));
```

My nuxt store/index.js file on the frontend

```
export const state = () => ({
  redirect: null,
})

export const mutations = {
  SET_REDIRECT(state, redirect) {
    state.redirect = redirect
  },
}

export const actions = {
  nuxtServerInit({ commit, dispatch }, { $dayjs, req }) {
    console.log('req.user is', req.user);
    console.log('req.session is', req.session);
    console.log('req.headers are', req.headers);
    console.log('req.headers.cookie is ', req.headers.cookie);
    commit('me/SET_USER', req.user)
  },
}
```

Comment: The association between session cookie and session exists only in the backend. You try to log the session on the frontend server.

Comment: i see, then how do I retrieve the session user on the frontend server

Comment: Why do you need the session user on the frontend server? The frontend only serves as a gateway to the backend, it has no functionality of its own (at least no functionality that would depend on the user).

Comment: @HeikoTheißen how do I get the user if they refresh the page after login, hence the session

Comment: After page refresh, the backend still knows the user in its session, and the frontend need not know it.

Comment: how to keep the user logged in on the frontend if you refresh the page

Comment: The user is never logged on to the frontend, only to the backend.

Answer (score 0):

The association between session cookie and session exists only in the backend. And that is sufficient, because the frontend only serves as a gateway to the backend, it has no functionality of its own (at least no functionality that would depend on the user).

After a page refresh, the backend still knows the user in its session, and the frontend need not know it. In other words: The user is never logged on to the frontend, only to the backend.

Answer (score 0):

The reason req.user is undefined is because axios does not send credentials by default (talking strictly about the axios module) Include

```
  axios: {
    // Workaround to avoid enforcing hard-coded localhost:3000: https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module/issues/308
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000',
    credentials: true,
  },
```

as mentioned [here](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options#credentials) and it should work fine